# ArrayList vs Vector passing by reference

Tags: java, c++

In Java, if you have the following code, list1 and list2 end up pointing to the same object, so a change in list2 will result in a change in list1.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2 = list1;
list2.set(0, 10);

for(int i =0; i<list1.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(list1.get(i));
}
for(int i =0; i<list2.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(list2.get(i));
}
```

And the output ends up being:

```
10
2
3

10
2
3
```

However, in C++, the behavior is different?

```
vector<int> list1;
list1.push_back(1);
list1.push_back(2);
list1.push_back(3);
vector<int> list2;
list2 = list1;
list2.at(0) = 10;
for(int i =0; i<list1.size(); i++){
    cout << list1[i] << endl;
}

for(int i=0; i<list2.size(); i++){
    cout << list2[i] << endl;
}
```

The output ends up being:

```
1
2
3

10
2
3
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: Different languages; different assignment semantics.

Comment: In your Java code you assign *references*. in your C++ code you assign *objects*. Make it `vector<int>&` or `vector<int>*` and you'll get Java in C++! ;)

Comment: More details: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

In Java, the `=` operator on (assignment-compatible) reference types simply copies the reference value. (Think *pointer* if you're coming from the C/C++ world.) The key thing to keep in mind is that in Java, no variable is ever an object; it is either a primitive value or a *reference* to an object.

In your C++ example, the `=` operator is working on actual objects, not on references. (With other data types, the story might be different.) From [the docs for `std::vector::operator=`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/):

> Assigns new contents to the container, replacing its current contents, and modifying its size accordingly.

So in C++, `list2` remains a separate `vector` object after the assignment, just with a copy of the contents of `list1`. In Java, the second `ArrayList` object you assigned to `list2` becomes garbage once you reassign `list2` to be a reference to the same object as `list1`.

Comment: Just one question. When I write ArrayList<Integer> list2 = list1, why does this behavior now mimic that of C++?

Comment: @DannyLiu - It does? That should definitely not be happening. Please check your code again. If it is indeed behaving like the C++ code, please edit your question and post the revised version and its output.

Comment: Oh shoot it doesn't. My bad

Comment: @DannyLiu - Good. Balance has been restored to the Force. :)

Answer (score 1):

To explain simply:

Java uses reference semantics. In this case you have two names (list1, list2) for the same object after the line list2 = list1.

C++ uses value semantics. The *values* of list1 are copied to list2 and you have a new unrelated object (list2) that may be mutated without affecting the copied object(list1).

Comment: Of course, you can do the same thing in Java with `list2 = new ArrayList(list1);`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to have the same behavior in C++ is to declare list2 as a reference - however, this requires that the assignment occur in list2's declaration and not after:

```
vector<int> &list2 = list1;
```